# webkitTransitionEnd eventListener Firing Twice

Tags: javascript, events

I'm trying to write something that has a callback function for a webkitTransitionEnd eventListener, but for some reason the eventListener is getting fired twice (doSomething is executed twice).

```
Something.prototype.functionOne = function() {
    this.lightbox = document.createElement('div');
    if (this.transitions)
        this.element.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', this, false);

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        this.element.className = 'visible';
    }.bind(this), 0);
}

Something.prototype.handleEvent = function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.doSomething();
}
```

This doesn't work on Safari 5.1 without calling doSomething twice. I don't want to remove the eventListener on the first run, I just want it to execute once when the class is changed.

Live http://mynameisraj.com/code/cssbox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some investigation, it appears to me that `handleEvent` is being called once each for two separate [`WebKitTransitionEvent`](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Reference/WebKitTransitionEventClassReference/WebKitTransitionEvent/WebKitTransitionEvent.html) events, which differ in `propertyName` – the first event has the `propertyName` of `"opacity"`; the other has `"-webkit-transform"`.

I presume that `handleEvent` is always called once for each CSS property that finishes animation, followed by one with `"-webkit-transform"` for the entire block of transitions.

To fix your example, I believe this will work:

```
Something.prototype.handleEvent = function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    if ( event.propertyName === "-webkit-transform" ) {
        this.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: That solved it. I should have known that it'll fire once for each transition!

Comment: Thanks for this, just sorted out a problem I've been having as well! Also, for anyone using jquery you can do this using event.originalEvent.propertyName by the way.

Comment: I have the same problem, but in my case it is firing twice for the same prop!!?